# Global JavaScript event for missing resources

Tags: javascript

I wonder if that is possible to handle missing resources of a web page all togather including missin images from `background: url(...)` from CSS.

I have checked `document.addEventListener("error", eventHandler, true);`, `window.onerror` and also `performance.getEntries()` but none of them reports missing images referenced from CSS even from inlined styles.

Best base to also handle missing resources from other origins e.g. broken fonts referenced from CDNs.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to list all resources using `window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")`, then try to download each of them using ajax to see if it produces a 404. However there are 2 major drawbacks to consider:

- this isn't an event listener, you have to execute the check after a reasonable amout of time to let the browser load all resources, or execute it periodically;
- you must avoid to check for dynamic resources which could return a different result from the previous call, or the more dangerous case where a call to a resource produces an update of the data on the remote server (a very trivial example could be a view counter on an image);
- there is a chance that the ajax call results in different status code even if the resource is static, for example if the client is on an unstable network and the connection goes down between the two calls.

Anyway here is a starting point:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var resources = window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
        resources.forEach(function (resource) {
            $.get(resource.name).fail(function(e) {
                var msg = 'Failed to load resource '+resource.name+' requested by '+resource.initiatorType;
                var div = $('<div/>').text(msg);
                $('body').append(div);
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
};
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url('bar.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="foo.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thank your reply. Another big drawback is that it will download all the resources twice resulting on aditional traffic and if coincides with requests made by user could cause delays as browsers has limints on number of actice fetch requests. So while it's not suitable for production, it is still could be used for testing. Isn't there some event that is fired for such errors?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for networking because the browser will retrieve the resources from the local cache (except for the missing ones, which are never cached), unless the server disable the cache for particular resources (but this is tipically done only for dynamic resources, not for static content). You can verify this by looking at the networking tab of the dev tools (but be sure to uncheck "disable cache").

Comment: The event can be catched with `element.addEventListener('error', ...)`, but you have to attach the event to each element that would load the resource. Beside the fact that it could be hard to scan the document for all img, script, style, especially if the page content is changed dinamically, you would have no chance to listen for missing resources referenced within css rules. So both solutions have advantages as well disadvantages.

Comment: Here you can see the effective network calls: https://i.ibb.co/mG2RhHK/networking.png